# «Собрать свои силы для борьбы» - можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли так выразиться: «не желает собрать свои силы для борьбы?»

Answer (score 2):

В толковом словаре Ожегова:
**собрать**, -беру, -берёшь; -ал, -ала, -ало; собранный; сов.
8) **что**. Напрячь, приведя в активное состояние (свои способности, душевные силы).
*Собрать всё своё мужество. Собрать последние силы. Собрать мысли.*

*А все дело теперь именно в том, чтобы сознательный авангард пролетариата устремил свои помыслы и **собрал свои силы для революционной борьбы**...* (В. И. Ленин)

*Она искала политического центра, около которого могла бы **собрать свои силы для** этой тяжелой и опасной **борьбы*** (В. О. Ключевский).